# Is Eval my only option?

Tags: javascript

I'm wondering if Eval() is the only option I really have for calling scripts on my server and also executing the javascript on those files.

I see every where about security issue with Eval and people don't recommend it - so is there any safe way to request files with javascript and execute that JS ?

Comment: Why do you call scripts serverside?

Comment: Why would i call scripts from some one else's server unrelated to my website ? :S

Comment: I don't know, thats why I ask. I read that you were "calling scripts on your server an executing them [there]". So what do you want to achieve?

Comment: For example: i call a html file of a table...that table then needs to loop an array of data which is set in JS. But calling the file won't execute the JS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you don't have to eval, although if you trust the input doing so is alright. It is still better to transfer only data and not running code.

You can dynamically create a script tag:

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = 'path/to/javascript/to/run';
document.body.appendChild(script);
```

Comment: What if this also has HTML output ? There is no input its just a call. IF i can get it to execute the script it can use arrays set in my main JS script.

Comment: @Dave The call is input. So is the HTML returned from the server for that matter. If it has HTML in it then eval won't work either. You may want to return a json object containing both HTML and javascript and then eval the javascript part, or maybe you won't even need to eval it anymore since you can return functions you want to execute through JSON.

Comment: well i call a script to load the layout of a table but in that table i also need to loop some JS array to list rows of data in a html table. I can't send the array as the JS won't execute it just loads HTML. =/ Do you get what i mean ?

Comment: @Dave You should send the array as json and then parse it using JSON.parse.  see this: http://json.org/ and also look at other answers involving JSON and JSON.parse on stackoverflow

Comment: That doesn't make sense... if i call a file i can't send JSON data because it won't execute the JS on the file i just called. http://www.paste.to/NDc3NzAw see here, how can i loop the data array in my html file if the array is set in my main JS and JS doesn't execute when you request a file?

Comment: Send JSON and nothing else back. Then parse the JSON on the client using JSON.parse and loop through the array all in client side code that has always been on the client.

Comment: So i have to write the table etc in JS like innerHTML in my main JS script not the html file?

Comment: Have a separate file. `main.html` and `main.json`, when they're both loaded then you can loop though the json data. You'll have to use a modified version of `call_file` which does `var my_array = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);` and loops through it (or calls a callback function on the result), instead of inserting the result into a div.

Comment: have you got an example of this some where so i can see how its done ?

Comment: @Dave Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/Paulpro/9SfGu/ `load_file` works the same as your `call_file` and expects just text or HTML. `get_json` parses the JSON response and executes a callback on it.  Specifying the method is uneccessary and you should just use "GET" not "POST", but I had to use post to send data to the testing server to get the server to send it back.

Answer (score 0):

I do this extensively in an asp.net mcv3 web app to dynamicaly load in scripted partial views, using [jQuery.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

Answer (score 0):

Just document write a script include to the page. Then the client's browser will do it for you and you can pretty much ignore the security aspect of it.